# How do I replace the R in the words "R output:" with the picture I defined by \Rlogo?

Tags: lstdefinestyle, sasnrdisplay

Below is the my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\Rlogo}{\protect\includegraphics[height=1.8ex,keepaspectratio]{Rlogo.png}} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[english,noautotitles-r,countbylistings]{SASnRdisplay} 
\lstdefinestyle{r-output}{
    style = r-style,
    style = r-output-user
}
\lstdefinestyle{r-frame}{
    frame = single, 
    framesep = 0.0em
}

\begin{document}
\inputRoutput*[caption={ththyeyyyedhfhfh} ,numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny,label=code:r-out]{A2Output.txt}
\end{document}
```

Below is the A2Output.txt contents:

```
> S1
         [,1] [,2]
[1,] 2.333333  0.5
[2,] 0.500000  1.0
> S2
     [,1]     [,2]
[1,]  1.0 1.500000
[2,]  1.5 2.333333
> Sp
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 1.666667 1.000000
[2,] 1.000000 1.666667

#(a)(ii)
> T2
             [,1]
[1,] 2.218671e-31
> c2
[1] 7.708647

#(b)(i)
> Xbar
[1] 192.0 278.4
> S
          [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 121.77778 76.33333
[2,]  76.33333 92.93333
```

I have attached the `\Rlogo` picture.[image]
Please I am kindly requesting on how to alter the caption style in the way I described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the listing is governed by `\SnRRoutputname`, so you can

```
\renewcommand{\SnRRoutputname}{\Rlogo}
```

This will, however, leave you with a numbered `\Rlogo`. Depending on your setup, it might be easier to just use `title={\Rlogo: <caption>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{A2Output.txt}
> S1
         [,1] [,2]
[1,] 2.333333  0.5
[2,] 0.500000  1.0
> S2
     [,1]     [,2]
[1,]  1.0 1.500000
[2,]  1.5 2.333333
> Sp
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 1.666667 1.000000
[2,] 1.000000 1.666667

#(a)(ii)
> T2
             [,1]
[1,] 2.218671e-31
> c2
[1] 7.708647

#(b)(i)
> Xbar
[1] 192.0 278.4
> S
          [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 121.77778 76.33333
[2,]  76.33333 92.93333
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\Rlogo}{\protect\includegraphics[height=1.8ex,keepaspectratio]{example-image}} 
\usepackage{listings,graphicx}
\usepackage[english,noautotitles-r,countbylistings]{SASnRdisplay} 
\lstdefinestyle{r-output}{
    style = r-style,
    style = r-output-user
}
\lstdefinestyle{r-frame}{
    frame = single, 
    framesep = 0.0em
}

\begin{document}

\inputRoutput*[
  title={\Rlogo: ththyeyyyedhfhfh},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny
]{A2Output.txt}

\end{document}
```